# Can someone help me with some responsive css please?

Tags: css, drupal, responsive-design, themes, stylesheet

I'm using Drupal. I have added a sitename and slogan to my kickstart sub theme which is a subtheme of omega. i then added a telephone number through the branding.tpl.php file. When I resize the window, the branding text moves down and behind the rest of the elements on the page - it doesnt push everything else down like i would like it to.

The site I am working on is www.mediamatterstechnology.com, please could someone give me some suggestions on how to fix the responsiveness of this branding section.

What I would like to happen is that when you resize the window, the branding section moves down as it currently does, but pushes everything else down with it, rather than disappearing behind other items on the page.

Thank you so much for any help with this

Comment: can you show some of your code or views.

Comment: First change your slider, it has a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that `<hgroup class="site-name-slogan">` has a specified height of `150px`. Changing this to `auto` allows the text to expand into the space it requires.

This introduces a second problem though, in that the absolutely positioned menu widget interferes with it. How you solve this could have design implications though and there any many possibilities.

One solution is to force a bottom margin on the `hgroup` when the design is in the mobile version of the layout with the following CSS rule:

```
body.responsive-layout-mobile hgroup.site-name-slogan { margin-bottom: 40px; }
```